# Ubuntu installation from Windows 7, reboots again

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I am running Windows 7, and wanted to install Ubuntu from my USB. Whenever I come to the option, where I can choose whether to replace Windows or install it additionally, I click next and the computer reboots. It reboots to the installation settings. I tried to switch my BIOS to boot from the hard disk in between, but it throws me back to Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So your running the installation whilst your booted into Windows 7.

Verify that the files have been installed to the correct partition, and they exist on disk:

if so:

Is there an entry in your boot menu? (msconfig.exe > boot) or check via command line: bcdedit (run cmd with admin rights)

Basic output without ubuntu installed would be:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {8464683a-2de9-11e2-8421-e47db9542646}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 10

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {8464683c-2de9-11e2-8421-e47db9542646}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {8464683a-2de9-11e2-8421-e47db9542646}
nx                      OptIn

C:\Windows\system32>
```

check if a second entry to boot to linux has been created, if it hasn't then search up online on how tocreate the boot entry